# Converting an equation into a function

Tags: calculus, vectors

I've got a surface in the form $z=x^2 - y^2$, and I need to get the gradient vector of it at a point, but I'm not sure how to go about this as every other time I've done this, the surface has been in the form $f(x,y,z)=...$.
It's been suggested to me to just define my own function $f(x,y,z)=x^2 - y^2 - z$, but surely that's no longer equivalent to the original equation? I'm completely stumped any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x^2-y^2-x$ should be $x^2-y^2-z=f(x,y,z)$ right? You are missing the z

Comment: Yep! Thank you for catching that, I fixed it in the original post.

Comment: The equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ gives your original equation.

Comment: It is in fact equivalent to your original equation, as $z=x^2-y^2$ if and only if $0=x^2-y^2-z$ (adding elements to the equation is equivalent).

Comment: The normal vector field is given by $\nabla f(x,y,z)$. Is that what you want? There is also a gradient field $(\partial z/\partial x, \partial z/\partial y).$

Comment: I understand $0=x^2 - y^2 - z$ is equivalent but is that then enough to define $f(x,y,z)=x^2 - y^2 - z$?

Comment: Yes. But note that you do note that the gradient of $f$ is in fact normal to the surface. If you want the tanget space, you need to the the orthogonal complement.

Comment: Okay, thank you for everyone's help!

Comment: The graph of $y=x^2$ can be regarded as a *level curve* $g(x,y)=c$ of the function $g(x,y)=x^2-y$ for $c=0$. In the same way, the graph of $z=x^2-y^2$ can be regarded as a level *surface* of $f(x,y,z)=c$ of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2-z$ for $c=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Stolen from John above*

> The graph of $y=x^2$ can be regarded as a *level curve* $g(x,y)=c$ of the function $g(x,y) = x^2 - y$ for $c = 0$. In the same way, the graph of $z=x^2 - y^2$ can be regarded as a level *surface* of $f(x,y,z) = c$ of the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 - z$ for $c=0$.